# Create the List Type dynamically (or a different kind of collection?)

Tags: c#, reflection, collections

I am writing a class that reads different kinds of CSV files.  It picks out the important information based on Model classes, where the properties of the model class are the column names that I want to grab.  For example, I could have an OutlookModel with columns FromAddress and ToAddress.  Or I could have a SalesforceModel with totally different columns.

When the reader class parses through the rows and columns, it loads up the cells into an instance of the model class.  In the code below, the argument className = OutlookModel.  The most relevant lines of code here are the signature and the return...

```
    protected void MapColumns(string row, string className, List<OutlookModel> list)
    {
        string[] cols = row.Split(',');
        // create a model to save the important columns
        var model = Activator.CreateInstance(nameSpace, nameSpace + className);
        int j = 0;
        if (cols.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var c in cols)
            {
                // is this column index one of our important columns?
                if (Ordinals.ContainsKey(j))
                {
                    // this is a column we care about, so set the model property
                    model.GetType().GetProperty(Ordinals[j]).SetValue(model, c);
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
        list.Add(model);
    }
```

The problem I am having is the collection of model objects.  If I define the object as List< OutlookModel > in the arguments, then the method is not extensible.  If I define it as List< object >, then (i think) I have to cast the inside list to use my properties which are all different between the models.

I am fairly new to C#.  Is there a better way to capture these different model types into a list/array/collection/whatever so that I can then apply logic to the lists?

Comment: What contains `Ordinals` during runtime? Do you change its values before invoking this method?

Comment: Ordinals is a dictionary<int,string> that contains the column index of the header of an excel file.  The header of the excel file matches the property of a model, and that becomes the value of the dictionary.  For example, if the third column is "FromAddress", then it would be Ordinals[2] = FromAddress.  The Ordinals dictionary is loaded with the first row of the excel file, then this MapColumns method is ran for each subsequent row.

Comment: Do you have to use this method signature?

Comment: No. That's what I am trying to figure out. What should I do to gather up my model objects? List is too strongly typed I think.

Comment: I think you should use a generic method. I'll throw a sample together. Do you have control over the models used?

Comment: Yes just me coding. All by my lonesome. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all i suggest to add a custom attribute to mark the properties you want to read from the csv, so you don't run into any problem when you have to add something later and you don't have to rely on too many magic strings. Here is my test setup:

```
    class ReadFromCsvAttribute : Attribute { }

    class OutlookModel
    {
        public int DontSetThisValueFromCsv { get; set; }

        [ReadFromCsv]
        public string FromAddress { get; set; }

        [ReadFromCsv]
        public string ToAddress { get; set; }
    }

    class SalesForceModel
    {
        [ReadFromCsv]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ReadFromCsv]
        public string Age { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string outlookSample = "Id,FromAddress,ToAddress,Useless\r\n" +
                               "1,a@b.com,c@d.com,asdf\r\n" +
                               "3,y@z.com,foo@bar.com,baz";

        string salesForceSample = "Id,Name,Age\r\n" +
                                  "1,John,30\r\n" +
                                  "2,Doe,100";

        var outlook = ReadFromCsv<OutlookModel>(outlookSample);

        var salesForce = ReadFromCsv<SalesForceModel>(salesForceSample);

    }
```

I put together this generic method to read whatever model you want from the data:

```
static List<T> ReadFromCsv<T>(string data)
{
    var objs = new List<T>();
    var rows = data.Split(new[] {"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);

    //create index, header dict
    var headers = rows[0].Split(',').Select((value, index) => new {value, index})
        .ToDictionary(pair => pair.index, pair => pair.value);

    //get properties to find and cache them for the moment
    var propertiesToFind = typeof (T).GetProperties().Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes<ReadFromCsvAttribute>().Any());

    //create index, propertyinfo dict
    var indexToPropertyDict =
        headers.Where(kv => propertiesToFind.Select(x => x.Name).Contains(kv.Value))
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => propertiesToFind.Single(p => p.Name == x.Value));

    foreach (var row in rows.Skip(1))
    {
        var obj = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

        var cells = row.Split(',');
        for (int i = 0; i < cells.Length; i++)
        {
            if (indexToPropertyDict.ContainsKey(i))
            {
                //set data
                indexToPropertyDict[i].SetValue(obj, cells[i]);
            }
        }
        objs.Add(obj);
    }

    return objs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate.  I'll have to spend some time analyzing this.  It's very different than what I know today.  I appreciate you writing it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another sample. Since you're new to c#, I've avoided linq and extension methods as much as possible. Just copy it into a console app and run.

Also, I like theHennyy recommendation of using .net attributes to describe a class but only if you have full control of your ecosystem.

```
public class Account
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class LastNameAccount
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test1();
    }

    private static void Test1()
    {
        /*
         * defines the result of your CSV parsing. 
         */
        List<string> csvColumns = new List<string> { "FirstName", "LastName" };
        List<List<string>> csvRows = new List<List<string>>() {
            new List<string>(){"John","Doe"},
            new List<string>(){"Bill", "Nie"}
        };

        //Map the CSV files to Account type and output it
        var accounts = Map<Account>(csvColumns, csvRows);
        if (accounts != null)
        {
            foreach (var a in accounts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Account: {0} {1}", a.FirstName, a.LastName);
            }
        }

        //Map the CSV files to LastNameAccount type and output it
        var accounts2 = Map<LastNameAccount>(csvColumns, csvRows);
        if (accounts2 != null)
        {
            foreach (var a in accounts2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Last Name Account: {0} {1}", a.LastName, a.Address);
            }
        }
    }


    private static List<T> Map<T>(List<string> columns, List<List<string>> rows)
        where T : class, new()
    {
        //reflect the type once and get valid columns
        Type typeT = typeof(T);
        Dictionary<int, PropertyInfo> validColumns = new Dictionary<int, PropertyInfo>();
        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columns.Count; columnIndex++)
        {
            var propertyInfo = typeT.GetProperty(columns[columnIndex]);
            if (propertyInfo != null)
            {
                validColumns.Add(columnIndex, propertyInfo);
            }
        }

        //start mapping to T 
        List<T> output = null;
        if (validColumns.Count > 0)
        {
            output = new List<T>();
            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                //create new T
                var tempT = new T();

                //populate T's properties
                foreach (var col in validColumns)
                {
                    var propertyInfo = col.Value;
                    var columnIndex = col.Key;

                    propertyInfo.SetValue(tempT, row[columnIndex]);
                }

                //add it
                output.Add(tempT);
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for doing this!